# How can i run a powershell script continually for 15min?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that connects to a database as follows:

```
try
{
# This is a simple user/pass connection string.
# Feel free to substitute "Integrated Security=True" for system logins.
$connString = "Data Source=YourInstance;Database=YourDB;User 
 ID=YourUser;Password=YourPassword"

 #Create a SQL connection object
 $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connString

 #Attempt to open the connection
 $conn.Open()
 if($conn.State -eq "Open")
 {
    # We have a successful connection here
    # Notify of successful connection
    Write-Host "Test connection successful"
    $conn.Close()
}
# We could not connect here
 # Notify connection was not in the "open" state
}

catch
{
    # We could not connect here
    # Notify there was an error connecting to the database
}
```

Now is there a way that i can continually run this script for 15min or 30min with a
20sec delay in between each run ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`do` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_do?view=powershell-7.3) with the condition to break it when the elapsed time of a [`StopWatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-7.0) is greater than 15 minutes. For the 20 second intervals you can use `Start-Sleep`.

```
$runtime = [timespan]::FromMinutes(15)
$timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

do {
    try {
        $connString = 'Data Source=YourInstance;....'
        $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connString
        $conn.Open()
        if ($conn.State -eq 'Open') {
            Write-Host 'Test connection successful'
            $conn.Close()
        }
    }
    catch {
        # We could not connect here
        # Notify there was an error connecting to the database
    }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
}
while($runtime -ge $timer.Elapsed)
```

Comment: can i break out of the loop ? I have modified the question to make it simpler

Comment: @Traci I dont understand what you mean. You can add more code after this loop, i.e. to send an email. If you want to break earlier from the loop you can reduce the minutes in the `$runtime` variable or if you want to break manually you can use the `break` keyword.

Comment: @Traci what you're looking for is a retry counter. however that was not specified in the initial question and i've already answered the initial question. will not edit this answer any further. you should be asking a follow up question and accept this one if it has already answered the initial question.